# How to read a file from AWS S3 bucket to Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to read a JSON file in AWS S3 bucket into a Python list of dicts. My AWS credentials are stored in env:

```
os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = "my_access_key"
os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = "my_secret_access_key"
os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] = 'eu-central-1'
```

Now I try to read the file:

```
f = open("s3://bucketname/folder/file.json")
```

And I get the following:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 's3://bucketname/folder/file.json'
```

(I can read the file via `boto3` but I wonder if there is a way for direct access like the above.)

Comment: `open` can't read files in s3. Use the AWS SDK to download the file first.

Comment: Reading the file via `boto3` is almost always the best. There are ways to make the s3 objects accessible as plain files via `open`, for situations where you can't change the code, but if you can use `boto3`, that will be much better

Comment: You are looking for s3fs.
You can mount s3 on a directory.
s3fs mybucket /path/to/mountpoint -o passwd_file=${HOME}/.passwd-s3fs
check here:
https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse
Be careful with charges.

Comment: you san use smart-open library to use open context manager https://pypi.org/project/smart-open/

Answer (score 0):

The basic options are:

- Use an AWS SDK (eg boto3 for Python) to call the Amazon S3 API and **download the object** to your local disk. Your code can then open the local file.
- Use the [smart-open · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/smart-open/) Python library, which can recognise S3 URLs and will make your code perform correctly. It calls the AWS APIs on your behalf.